# How to scroll horizontally knowing that the required tab has no unique ID (Appium using Java)

Tags: java, appium, uiautomation, mobile-automation

What I want to do is scrolling horizontally in a tab that doesn't have a `unique ID`. I have code how to scroll `using id` and `textmatches` like this example:

```
driver.findElement (MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()
.resourceId(" + Container +"))
.setAsHorizontalList().scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector()
.textMatches(" + Textmatch + ").instance(0))"));
```

So what should I do if I don't have the `resource-id` and `textMatches`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`mobile:shell` command](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/) to swipe to the given direction like:

   ```
   int starX=0;
   int endX=0;
   int startY=0; 
   int endY=0;
   //change the above values according to your swipe direction
   Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
   args.put("command", "input");
   args.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("swipe", startX,
   startY, endX, endY));

   while (driver.findElements(By.xpath("your element locator here")).size() == 0) {
       driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", args);
   }
   ```
2. You can use [`mobile:swipe` command](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/) like:

   ```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
   params.put("direction", "down");
   params.put("element", yourElement.getId());
   js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", params);
   ```
3. You can go for [SwipeWhileNotFound](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SwipeWhileNotFound) command (it's provided by [SeeTest - Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension)) like:

   ```
   seetest.swipeWhileNotFound("Down", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "seetest.swipeWhileNotFound("Down", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "xpath=your_element_locator", 0, 1000, 5, true)", 0, 1000, 5, true)
   ```

Going forward consider adding to your question essential information regarding source and target views, preferably via [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html) hierarchy dumps - this way we'll be able to come up with more precise answers instead of generic ones.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dmitri's methods, you can also use TouchActions, as I do in my code:

```
/**
 * This method scrolls based upon the passed parameters
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param int startx - the starting x position
 * @param int starty - the starting y position
 * @param int endx - the ending x position
 * @param int endy - the ending y position
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void scroll(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy) {

    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);

    touchAction.longPress(PointOption.point(startx, starty))
               .moveTo(PointOption.point(endx, endy))
               .release()
               .perform();

}

/**
 * This method does a swipe upwards
 * @author Bill Hileman
 */
public void scrollDown() {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting y location set to 80% of the height (near bottom)
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
    //Ending y location set to 20% of the height (near top)
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
    //x position set to mid-screen horizontally
    int startx = (int) size.width / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, startx, endy);

}

/**
 * This method does a swipe left
 * @author Bill Hileman
 */
public void swipeLeft() {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting x location set to 95% of the width (near right)
    int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.95);
    //Ending x location set to 5% of the width (near left)
    int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
    //y position set to mid-screen vertically
    int starty = size.height / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, endx, starty);

}

/**
 * This method does a swipe right
 * @author Bill Hileman
 */
public void swipeRight() {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting x location set to 5% of the width (near left)
    int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
    //Ending x location set to 95% of the width (near right)
    int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.95);
    //y position set to mid-screen vertically
    int starty = size.height / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, endx, starty);

}

/**
 * This method does a swipe downwards
 * @author Bill Hileman
 */
public void scrollUp() {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting y location set to 20% of the height (near bottom)
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
    //Ending y location set to 80% of the height (near top)
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
    //x position set to mid-screen horizontally
    int startx = size.width / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, startx, endy);

}
```